# Sigma matrices and quaternion correspondence

Tags: group-theory, permutations, rotations, group-isomorphism, quaternions

I'm trying to learn the mathematics behind spinors and I've come across sigma matrices and quaternions, both used to describe 3D rotations. Now it is possible to notice that any squared pair of sigma matrices returns the negative identity:

$$ \left( \sigma_i \sigma_j \right)^2 = - \mathrm{Id_2}, i \neq j$$

and any pair of sigma matrices anticommute with the "following" pair:

$$ \left( \sigma_i \sigma_j \right) \left( \sigma_j \sigma_k \right) = - \left( \sigma_j \sigma_k \right) \left( \sigma_i \sigma_j \right), i \neq j \neq k$$

Now these seem to be the same properties that characterize quaternion units $i$, $j$ and $k$:

$$ i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = -1 $$
$$ ij = -ji $$
$$ jk = -kj $$
$$ ki = -ik $$

Iin the source I'm using (which is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0w5QnhS_55U) video), the author affirms that it is possible to associate sigma matrices and quaternion units in this way:

$$ i \to -\sigma_y \sigma_z $$
$$ j \to -\sigma_z \sigma_x $$
$$ k \to -\sigma_x \sigma_y $$

But isn't this association kind of arbitrary? For example this should also be a valid association:

$$ i \to -\sigma_x \sigma_y $$
$$ j \to -\sigma_y \sigma_z $$
$$ k \to -\sigma_z \sigma_x $$

Moreover, if this reasoning is correct, any association of this kind should be valid:

$$ i \to -\sigma_l \sigma_m $$
$$ j \to -\sigma_m \sigma_n $$
$$ k \to -\sigma_n \sigma_l $$

(with $l \neq m \neq n$). Now I get that the association proposed by the author of the video is the most intuitive one: a rotation on the $xy$ is kind of associated to a rotation about the $z$ axis, since the $k$ is associated to an expression where $\sigma_z$ doesn't appear. But, if my reasoning up until now is correct, is this the only justification for this association to be chosen among all the possible ones?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly are your $\sigma$-matrices? Formulas (019a-d) show a much clearer mapping. On top of $\mathbf{i}^2=\mathbf{j}^2=\mathbf{k}^2=-1$ we have the very important relationship $\mathbf{ij=k}$ which is anti-symmetric in $\mathbf{i,j,k}\,.$
That means: $\mathbf{ji=-k}\,,\mathbf{ik=-j}$ and so on. The same algebra holds for the Pauli matrices after they got multiplied by $-i\,.$ Now I come to the point of your question: If you cyclically permute the mapping $\{\mathbf{i,j,k}\}\leftrightarrow\{-i\sigma_1,-i\sigma_2,-i\sigma_3\}$ you obviously get the same quaternion algebra.

Comment: .... And this is all that counts. The formulas (019a-d) are in [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/272563/304394).

Comment: It is completely arbitrary in the sense that you're asking. We could even choose any orthonormal imaginary quaternions $i', j', k'$ instead of $i,j,k$, or make similar combinations of sigma matrices.